# Recording user interactions in React Native / Snap Carousel - firstItem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, carousel

I have been having this issue for a couple of days and cannot seem to find a solution.

I would like to record the user's interaction on a database. I am displaying data using a React Native Snap Carousel, and need to record if the item was viewed by the user. To do this, and as described in other stack overflow questions, I am using "onSnapToItem". onSnapToItem is triggered everytime I change from one slide to another. Then, if the user views the slide for more than 2 seconds, I count that as an interaction.

The problem is that onSnapToItem is not triggered on the firstItem (which makes sense, because I am not changing slide). Can anybody think of a solution?

```
      <Carousel
              vertical
              layout={"default"}
              ref={_carousel}
              data={promos}
              renderItem={_renderItem}
              autoplay={true}
              autoplayInterval={4000}
              onSnapToItem = { (index) => {
                clearTimeout(writeDelay)
                writeDelay=setTimeout (()=>{
                  console.log(promos[index].id)
                },2000)
                }}
              onEndReached={_retrieveMore}
              />
```

Comment: On initial load you should add a useEffect hook with empty array to run the function when the component renders

Comment: Hey Jason, I think that won't work, because when the component is mounted I first download the data from the database and the time that it takes for the firstItem to be ready can vary...

Comment: Hmm hard to say but if you have an async/await call or a promise you could fire after the data is loaded. Basically the useEffect is acting as a replacement for componentDidMount

Comment: i did something like that based on Nooruddin's comment below, but it still doesnt trigger because there is no slide change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically snap to item on screen focus.

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => this._carousel.snapToItem(0), 1000);

  // if above code doesn't work then you can try is for first item
  writeDelay=setTimeout (()=>{
     console.log(promos[0].id); // index here is 0 for first item
  },1000)
}

...

render() {
  <Carousel
    ...
    ref={c => { this._carousel = c }}
  />
}`
```

Comment: Hey Nooruddin! I think this should be the way to go, but for some reason it doesnt seem to work... I am calling it after the data of the carousel has been populated, but it doesnt seem to make a difference...

Comment: So I have been investigating on where the problem is, if i call snapToItem(3) it does work, but not snapToItem(0) - i imagine that because that is already the active slide, it doesnt trigger... Can you think of how to fix this? Thank you!!

Comment: I have updated my answer of what you can do for first time as alternate

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [library](https://github.com/SvanBoxel/visibility-sensor-react-native) `@svanboxel/visibility-sensor-react-native`